# Linking numpy/scipy to serial ATLAS

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

My operating system is Fedora 16 (although I have had the same issue on other distros).

I want to build numpy/scipy linking to serial ATLAS (rather than threaded).  It would seem this involves uncommenting the following lines in my site.cfg file:

```
[DEFAULT]
library_dirs = /usr/lib64/atlas
include_dirs = /usr/local/include
[blas_opt]
libraries = f77blas, cblas, atlas
[lapack_opt]
libraries = lapack, f77blas, cblas, atlas
```

I have done this, but when I build the package via

```
python setup.py build
```

It still links to the threaded libraries eg.

```
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  FOUND:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is already one year old, so I'm writing this answer in case anyone would have same problem.

I would probably manually remove/rename threaded atlas libs. It's a bit ugly but it should work.

Another solution could be to configure numpy like this:

```
[atlas]
library_dirs = /usr/lib64/atlas
atlas_libs = lapack, f77blas, cblas, atlas
```

There was also this [commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/ffd4332262ee0295cb942c94ed124f043d801eb6) in numpy saying that `{blas,lapack}_opt` sections are not actually read.